# No results display when running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am stumped. I am not receiving any errors or undefined errors when running this code just a blank return and then a new command line. I've run it about 100 times in the command prompt and still nothing.  I figured after 100 times it should display the "Congratulations message". Can anyone take a look and see what I am missing?  Thank you in advance.

```js
//Player Class

function Player(name, weapons) {
    this.playerName = name;
    this.playerHealth = 10;
    this.playerStrength = 2;
    this.playerWeapons = weapons;
}

Player.prototype.applyDamage = function(damage) {
    this.playerHealth = this.playerHealth - damage;
    console.log(this.playerName + " " + "has sustained " + " " + this.playerHealth + " " + "amount of damage.");
}

Player.prototype.isAlive = function() {
    if(this.playerHealth > 0)
     return true;
    else
     return false;
}

Player.prototype.attacksWith = function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    return (this.weapon[random]);
}

//Minion Class

function Minion(minion, health, strength) {
    this.minionName = 'Minion';
    this.minionHealth = 5;
    this.minionStrength = 2;
}

Minion.prototype.applyDamage = function(damage) {
    this.minionHealth = this.minionHealth - damage;
    console.log(this.minionName + " " + "has sustained " + " " + this.minionHealth + " " + "amount of damage.");
}

Minion.prototype.isAlive = function() {
    if(this.minionHealth > 0)
     return true;
    else
     return false;
}

Minion.prototype.attack = function(playerName) {
    playerName.applyDamage(this.minionHealth);
}

//Weapons Class
function Weapons(weapon) {
    this.weaponName = weapon;
    this.weapondamage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
}

var weaponsCache = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

var axe = new Weapons("skullCracker");
var hxfx = new Weapons("Hexaflexagon");
var blade = new Weapons("Balmung");
var mario = new Weapons("cappy");
var fire = new Weapons("Fire Breath");
var staff = new Weapons("Magic Staff");
var hrp = new Weapons("Harpe");
var CobaltWep = new Weapons("Cobalt Rifle");

var w = new Weapons([i]);
weaponsCache[i] = w;
}

var player = [];
var i = 0;
while (i < 8) {
 
 var m = new Player();
 player[i] = m;
 i++;
}

//Game Class

function Game(players, minions) {
this.players = [];
this.minions = [];
}

 function attack(player, minion) {
    while (playerName.isAlive() && minionName.isAlive()) {
    actualDamage = player.strength * this.damage();
    minion.applyDamage(actualDamage);

    if (minion.isAlive())
  minion.attack(player);
 else
  break;
 }
}

function createMinions() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i > 20) {

        var m = new Minion();
        minion[i] = m;
        i++;
    }
}

 function createPlayers() {
  var player = []; {
    var ph = new Player("Prophetic Hamster", weaponsCache);
    var mm = new Player("Mighty Mathematician", weaponsCache);
    var sieg = new Player ("Siegfried", weaponsCache);
    var bd = new Player ("Blue Dragon", weaponsCache);
    var ip = new Player("Iron Professor", weaponsCache)
 }
 
Game.prototype.play = function() {

console.log("Simulating Battle...");

createMinion();
createPlayer();

var i = 0,
count = 0;

while (i < 20) {
 
 if (minions[i].isAlive())
  count++;
 }

    if (count == 20) {
  
  i = 0;
  var flag = 0;
  
  while (i < 8) {
   
   if (players[i].isAlive())
    
   flag++;
   }
   
   while (count == 20 && flag > 0) {
    
    var randomPlayer, randomMinion;
    
    randomPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    randomMinion = math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    weapon = player.attackWith();
    attack(minions);
    attack(players);
    }
    
 count = 0;
 i = 0;
 
 while (i > 20) {
  
  if (minions[i].isAlive())
   count++;
  }
  
 flag = 0;
 i = 0;
 
 while (i < 8) {
  if (players[i].isAlive())
   flag++;
  }

    if (flag > count)
        console.log("Congratulations!! You have defeated Scarlet Byte");
 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Start adding debugging lines and see what is going on. console.log() is your friend.

Comment: I spy multiple syntax errors, could you please fix your alignment to make it easier to read?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `var i = 0;
  while (i > 20) { i++ }  ` is never going to execute.

Comment: So many unexited `while` loops.

Comment: Upvoted you just for writing Javascript the way God intended.

Comment: You have some lines which need attention. The one connexo has already pointed out. Also the line if(count==20) which is inside the while(count<20) will never be hit, meaning all the code inside it will never be hit. It's worth adding some debugger; calls and stepping through the code in the browser to check your logic and adjust what you need to. Chrome has great tools for this. F12 if you aren't already aware.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and for the fresh eyes! Corrected the loops and everything worked great!